# Where to start when studying Architectural Engineering by myself?

Tags: structural-engineering, building-physics, architecture, construction-management

I have this idea of creating my own curriculum for studying Architectural Engineering. I aim at talking with actual architectural engineers in my surroundings and ask them for advice on the topics I should study and help me with advancing.

By looking at the programs that universities offer all over the world I got a good idea of the topics to be covered, but since I'm in charge, I would like to personalize my own program. I'd like to cover both the engineering and design part.

If you're an architectural engineer, what topic would you suggest me to start with? What are the topics that you find especially useful and important in your career as an architect/engineer? What would you advise universities to change in their curriculum?

Some context: I'm especially interested in building and repair of houses, combining more classical designs with modern technologies.

Update: I am aware that by studying by myself I won't obtain the necessary license to perform as an engineer.

Comment: FYI - If you are studying this area with the aim of calling yourself an engineer afterwards, you must have a formally issued degree by a university/college that is accredited by the major engineering accreditation bureau in your country. A similar process exists for Architects as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of this (my wife is an engineer). I mainly want to do it out of interest.

Comment: I'll leave it to engineers in your interested field to post answers, but I'll point out the obvious - you should start with Newtonian physics with calculus.

Comment: @J.Ari - Depends on country. In the UK anyone can call themselves an engineer. The terms "Incorporated Engineer" and "Chartered Engineer" are protected though.

Comment: You can find some great free courses from the [Civil Engineering MIT OpenCourseware](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/civil-and-environmental-engineering/)

Comment: This kind of academic guidance question isn't on-topic for this site. You're better off asking this question on a different site or forum

Comment: @BarbalatsDilemma I have been thinking about this but I'd really like to er in contact with experienced engineers and their personal views on what they find important based on their daily work. I wouldn't know where to ask otherwise.

Comment: @Lesley there is an [Engineering subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/engineering/) although I cannot speak to the accuracy of the information their or the civility of the discourse. Otherwise I'm not sure where you should go, I only know that this kind of question is not on topic here

Comment: @BarbalatsDilemma I'll have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @BarbalatsDilemma FYI, it's also on Reddit /r/AskEngineers - and has (like here) also some valuable comments.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you take a look at Architectural Engineering Professional Societies in your local area. Most of these societies have recommended educational curriculum and continues educational opportunities. Attach is a link to [Architectural Engineering Institute](http://www.asce.org/architectural-engineering/architectural-engineering-institute/) which I believe is part of [American Society of Civil Engineers](http://www.asce.org/). Another organization that might be of interest to is [Construction Management Association of America](http://cmaanet.org/). Little bit of research in to these professional societies should enable you to create your own curriculum. Also take a look at [List of engineering societies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_engineering_societies).

Hope these will help you get started.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I have a strong connection to the local Architectural Engineering society though my social environment. FYI, I live in Spain. However, I'd also like to see the opinions of worldwide professionals.